# @SpringBootTest Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter'

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-mvc

I'm having problems with spring boot. I got the error Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-22 10:16:18.954 ERROR 13282 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!

**UserRepository**

```
 package com.spring.course.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.spring.course.domain.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM user u WHERE email = ?1 AND password = ?2")
    public Optional<User> login(String email, String password);

}
```

**UserRepositoryTests**

```
package com.spring.course.repository;

import static org.assertj.core.api.Assertions.assertThat;

import java.util.List;
import java.util.Optional;

import org.junit.FixMethodOrder;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.junit.runners.MethodSorters;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

import com.spring.course.domain.User;
import com.spring.course.enums.Role;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@FixMethodOrder(MethodSorters.NAME_ASCENDING)
@SpringBootTest

public class UserRepositoryTests {
    @Autowired private UserRepository userRepository;

    @Test
    public void AsaveTest() {
        User user = new User(null, "Kevin", "kevin.wingi@gmail.com", "123", Role.ADMINISTRATOR, null, null);
        User createdUser = userRepository.save(user);

        assertThat(createdUser.getId()).isEqualTo(1L);

    }

    @Test
    public void updateTest() {
        User user = new User(1L, "Kevin Wingi", "kevin.wingi@gmail.com", "123", Role.ADMINISTRATOR, null, null);
        User updatedUser = userRepository.save(user);

        assertThat(updatedUser.getName()).isEqualTo("Kevin Wingi");
    }

    @Test
    public void getByIdTest() {
        Optional<User> result = userRepository.findById(1L);
        User user = result.get();

        assertThat(user.getPassword()).isEqualTo("123");
    }

    @Test
    public void listTest() {
        List<User> users = userRepository.findAll();

        assertThat(users.size()).isEqualTo(1);
    }

    @Test
    public void loginTest() {
        Optional<User> result = userRepository.login("kevin.wingi@gmail.com", "123");
        User loggedUser = result.get();

        assertThat(loggedUser.getId()).isEqualTo(1L);
    }

}
```

**RequestSatageRepository**

```
package com.spring.course.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.spring.course.domain.Request;
import com.spring.course.domain.RequestStage;
import com.spring.course.enums.RequestState;

@Repository
public interface RequestSatageRepository extends JpaRepository<RequestStage, Long>{

    public List<RequestStage> findAllByRequest(Long id);

    @Query("UPDATE request SET state = ?2 WHERE id = ?1")
    public Request updateStatus(Long id, RequestState state);

}
```

**Error:**

```
Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2019-09-22 10:16:18.954 ERROR 13282 --- [  restartedMain] o.s.boot.SpringApplication               : Application run failed

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$114/160143719.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:845) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:877) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:549) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:141) ~[spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:744) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:391) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:312) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1215) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1204) [spring-boot-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at com.spring.course.SpringCourse2Application.main(SpringCourse2Application.java:10) [classes/:na]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter]: Factory method 'requestMappingHandlerAdapter' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 25 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'mvcConversionService' defined in class path resource [org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:627) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:607) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1321) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1160) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:555) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:515) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:320) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$$Lambda$114/160143719.getObject(Unknown Source) ~[na:na]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:318) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.resolveBeanReference(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:394) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:366) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$185f6af8.mvcConversionService(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:602) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.getConfigurableWebBindingInitializer(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:506) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.WebMvcConfigurationSupport.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcConfigurationSupport.java:564) ~[spring-webmvc-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(WebMvcAutoConfiguration.java:426) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$185f6af8.CGLIB$requestMappingHandlerAdapter$8(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$185f6af8$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$e76d82d3.invoke(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:244) ~[spring-core-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:363) ~[spring-context-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.WebMvcAutoConfiguration$EnableWebMvcConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$185f6af8.requestMappingHandlerAdapter(<generated>) ~[spring-boot-autoconfigure-2.1.8.RELEASE.jar:2.1.8.RELEASE]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:154) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.format.support.FormattingConversionService]: Factory method 'mvcConversionService' threw exception; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:185) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiate(ConstructorResolver.java:622) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    ... 53 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'requestRepository': Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Mixing of ? parameters and other forms like ?1 is not supported!
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1778) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:593) ~[spring-beans-5.1.9.RELEASE.jar:5.1.9.RELEASE]
    at org.springfr
```

Comment: show the code of RequestSatgeRepository

Comment: OK, I add RequestSatageRepository code.

Comment: are you sure the method parameter is  RequestState state, not RequestStage?

Comment: please post the code of RequestStage class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find out the problem there is no more support for @Query with ?1 and ?2 parameters it changes

** RequestRepository**

Now my class is:

```
package com.spring.course.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.spring.course.domain.Request;
import com.spring.course.enums.RequestState;

@Repository
public interface RequestRepository extends JpaRepository<Request, Long>{

    public List<Request> findAllByOwnerId(Long id);

    @Query("UPDATE request SET state = :state WHERE id = :id")
    public Request updateStatus(Long id, RequestState state);

}
```

** RequestSatageRepository**

```
package com.spring.course.repository;

import java.util.List;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.spring.course.domain.Request;
import com.spring.course.domain.RequestStage;
import com.spring.course.enums.RequestState;

@Repository
public interface RequestSatageRepository extends JpaRepository<RequestStage, Long>{

    public List<RequestStage> findAllByRequest(Long id);

    @Query("UPDATE request SET state = :state WHERE id = :id")
    public Request updateStatus(Long id, RequestState state);

}
```

** UserRepository**

```
package com.spring.course.repository;

import java.util.Optional;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

import com.spring.course.domain.User;

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {

    @Query("SELECT u FROM user u WHERE email = :email AND password = :password")
    public Optional<User> login(String email, String password);

}
```